# Application and SQL Server on external drive?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, usb, ssms, usb-drive

Is it possible to install SQL Server on an external drive and use it? Also, I am trying to install a software on my clients usb 3.0 flash drive from where they can operate it easily on any laptop or PC - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, SQL server is installed within an operating system and is dependant on registry entries and possibly other settings within Windows OS installation path. As such, even if you install SQL server on an external drive then attempt to connect that external drive to another machine, it will not work.

The alternative is to use a Linux installation with a Windows OS installed on a virtual machine along with SQL Server.

An other option is to look into a contenerized solution such a Docker.

Comment: can you help me with it? As i am new to this.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online. Try using Virtualbox, create a virtual machine, install windows and install SQL server

Comment: You are welcome. What did you select to do?

Comment: I am using Virtual Machine to achieve that.